# Which exchange rate should I use for calculating Bitcoin exchange rates?

Tags: api, exchange-rate

I'm using the [Blockchain exchange rate API](https://blockchain.info/api/exchange_rates_api) to add a Bitcoin exchange rate calculating function to one of my apps.  I'm not sure which value I should be using.  For each currency type (USD, EUR, etc.) four different rates are returned: "last," "buy," "sell," and "24h."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people are interested in the last value or the 24 hour average, it depends on the purpose of the application and the intent of the developer.